# Force 'Update & Shut down' button appearing

Tags: button, updates, shutdown

I would like to know if there is a way to **force displaing** in Windows 10 & 11 the buttons: '**Update and shut down**' (and **Update and restart)** ?

Thanks in advance.

Cramaboule

[image: Update and shut down]

Answer (score 0):

Searching on a PC, I found this reg key:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\Orchestrator`
`ShutdownFlyoutOptions` (REG_DWORD)

You can play with different options between `0 to 15`

You can as well hide power/retart/... buttons here:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideRestart` `value` `0 - 1` (REG_DWORD)

and here:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\current\device\Start` `HideRestart` `0 - 1` (REG_DWORD)

and power button on login screen:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` `shutdownwithoutlogon` `0 - 1` (REG_DWORD)

Cram...